# Cast down with reflection at runtime

Tags: java, reflection, casting

Considering following code

```
   public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A().main();
    }

    void main() {

        B b = new B();
        Object x = getClass().cast(b);

        test(x);
    }

    void test(Object x) {
        System.err.println(x.getClass());
    }

    class B extends A {
    }
}
```

I expected as output **"class A"** but i get **"class A$B"**.

Is there a way to cast down the object x to A.class so when using in a method call the runtime will think x is of A.class ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A cast doesn't change the actual type of the object. For example:

```
String x = "hello";
Object o = (Object) x; // Cast isn't actually required
System.out.println(o.getClass()); // Prints java.lang.String
```

If you want an object which is *actually* just an instance of `A`, you need to create an instance of `A` instead. For instance, you might have:

```
public A(B other) {
    // Copy fields from "other" into the new object
}
```

Comment: yes, after further thinking i got the same conclusion ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. Casting doesn't change the type of an object, it just changes what type you have a reference to.

For example, this code:

```
B b = new B();
A a = (A) b;
a.doSomething();
```

Doesn't take `b` and forcibly make it into an instance of `A`, and then call the `doSomething()` method in class A. All the casting does is allow you to reference the object of type `B` as if it were of type `A`.

You cannot change the runtime type of an object.